# Horizontal Scrollbar doesn't work. (Tkinter Python)

Tags: python, tkinter

```
def openEditWindow(self):
        # Crea una nuova finestra per la modifica dello studente
        self.editWindow = tk.Toplevel(self.master)
        self.editWindow.title("Modifica studente")
        self.editWindow.geometry("500x400")
        self.editWindow.resizable(True, True)

        # Label e Entry per modificare il nome dello studente
        self.name_label = tk.Label(self.editWindow, text="Nome")
        self.name_label.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)

        self.name_entry = tk.Entry(self.editWindow, textvariable=tk.StringVar(value=self.studente.nome))
        self.name_entry.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)

        # Label e Entry per modificare il cognome dello studente
        self.surname_label = tk.Label(self.editWindow, text="Cognome")
        self.surname_label.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)

        self.surname_entry = tk.Entry(self.editWindow, textvariable=tk.StringVar(value=self.studente.cognome))
        self.surname_entry.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)

        #Sezione VOTI
        self.colonnaframe = 0
        # Frame per Canvas
        self.frameContCanvas = tk.Frame(self.editWindow, width=150, height=150)
        self.frameContCanvas.grid(row=2, columnspan=2)

        # Canvas per FrameMaterie Container
        self.canvasFrameMateries = tk.Canvas(self.frameContCanvas, width=150, height=150)
        self.canvasFrameMateries.grid(row=0,columnspan=2)
        # Scrollbar orizzontale
        self.scrollbarH = tk.Scrollbar(self.frameContCanvas,orient=tk.HORIZONTAL)
        self.scrollbarH.grid(row=1,column=0)
        self.scrollbarH.config(command=self.canvasFrameMateries.xview)
        # ------- Frames Materie -------
        for self.x in Studente.materie:
            StudenteFrame.materie.append(self.frameMateria(self.canvasFrameMateries, self.x, self.colonnaframe))
            self.colonnaframe += 1

        # Config canvas
        self.canvasFrameMateries.config(width=150, height=150)
        self.canvasFrameMateries.config(xscrollcommand=self.scrollbarH.set)
        self.editWindow.update_idletasks()
        self.canvasFrameMateries.configure(scrollregion=self.canvasFrameMateries.bbox("all"))
```

The scrollbar seems unusable, grayed out and the self.canvasFrameMateries's width isn't 150, same for the height. I don't know what to do, i tried everything.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMwNO.png)

Comment: You haven't actually added anything to the Canvas to be scrolled; you have to use `.create_window()` and similar Canvas methods to actually put items into it.

Comment: There are frames in the self.canvasFrameMateries. for self.x in Studente.materie:
            StudenteFrame.materie.append(self.frameMateria(self.canvasFrameMateries, self.x, self.colonnaframe))
            self.colonnaframe += 1
I can send a pic of them.

Comment: What is `self.frameMateria`? It is better to provide a [mre].

Comment: `Studente` and `StudenteFrame` are both not defined. The code will not work. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: i posted just a part of the code. Maybe it's better if i post the full code.

Comment: @Cristian Anicito Actually, it's better if you post a minimal reproducible example as acw1668 states in the comment above.